# Why systemd-nspawn is slower than docker,podman and qemu?! how to Improve nspawn performance?

Tags: docker, performance, qemu, systemd-nspawn, podman

Why `nspawn` is slow compared to `docker` `podman` and even `qemu`?!
CPU tasks take twice of the time it takes in docker, podman or qemu

Here is a benchmark test I did:

First I disabled all the spectre/meltdown mitigations in the host kernel (and the qemu guest kernel in the case of qemu benchmark) using:

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=noibrs noibpb nopti nospectre_v2 nospectre_v1 l1tf=off nospec_store_bypass_disable no_stf_barrier mds=off tsx=on tsx_async_abort=off mitigations=off spectre_v2_user=off spec_store_bypass_disable=off nx_huge_pages=off kvm.nx_huge_pages=off kvm-intel.vmentry_l1d_flush=never srbds=off
```

**then I used this benchmark test:**

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/tsuna/contextswitch
cd contextswitch
time make
```

I tested `nspawn` with super full privileges:

```bsh
export SYSTEMD_NSPAWN_USE_CGNS=0
systemd-nspawn  --keep-unit --register=no --boot --capability=all --private-users=false --system-call-filter="@default @aio @basic-io @chown @clock @cpu-emulation @debug @file-system @io-event @ipc @keyring @memlock @module @mount @network-io @obsolete @privileged @process @raw-io @reboot @resources @setuid @signal @swap @sync @system-service @timer" --bind=/sys/fs/cgroup  --machine=testtt -D busterdir
```

I tested `podman` with privileges too:

```bsh
podman run --rm -it --privileged debian:10 bash
```

I tested `docker` with privileges too:

```bsh
docker run --rm -it  --privileged  debian:10 bash
```

I tested `qemu` with:

```bsh
qemu-system-x86_64 -name buster20210121210102 -m 2G -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp cores=4,threads=2,sockets=1 -object iothread,id=myio1 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=mydisk0,iothread=myio1 -drive file=buster20210121210102.qcow2,if=none,id=mydisk0,format=qcow2,aio=native,cache=none
```

and here are the results:

```bsh
# baremetal
real    0m12.998s

# nspawn
real    0m30.777s  <==== :(

# docker
real    0m15.127s

#podman
real    0m15.207s

# qemu without mitigations
real    0m15.979s
```

here I filled a request to improve nspawn performance which contain the full test result:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18370

Do you know why systemd-nspawn is slower? how can I improve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem of performance was because I thought that whitelisting the syscalls en nspawn with `--system-call-filter` will improve the performance, but as they explained me in systemd [mail](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2021-January/045890.html) list I should use `export SYSTEMD_SECCOMP=0`, because nspawn will still be processing syscalls when I whitelist them.

`SYSTEMD_SECCOMP` was added in systemd v247 (debian buster have v241 but backport repository have v247).

so to make nspawn as quick as the baremetal host do:

```bsh
export SYSTEMD_SECCOMP=0
systemd-nspawn --capability=all -D ./bbusterboot --boot
```

this is equivalent to `--privileged` in `docker/podman`, and there is no need to use `--system-call-filter` if we use `SYSTEMD_SECCOMP`.

of course this is not good for security, so do it in a safe environment when running a trusted code only.

and if you want max performance which will add performance to baremetal, nspawn, docker, podman or what ever you are using, then disable all the spectre/meltdown mitigations as I did in the question above (but this is not good for security too if you run untrusted code like browsers with ad's for example).

---

read this for more details: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18370

Comment: Commenting here what was clarified at the github-thread to provide context here. The systemd-nspawn cmd has "--boot" so *overall* runtime will be higher due to booting entire OS (whereas docker & podman run the process as PID1 as usual). The answer was that it doesn't matter for this test because timing was only of process execution after boot (& same for qemu VM test). Note also that there are *3* ways to "run" a systemd-nspawn container: [1] --boot (full OS), [2] --as-pid2 (run executable as child of minimal stub init), [3] otherwise (without either flag) run executable as PID1.